# Can I determine my app's buildType in my build.gradle at run time?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-type

I need to be able to bump my versionCode only for a particular buildType called "`release_beta`". I have a function that bumps it just fine. I've discovered that buildTypes doesn't let you override the versionCode. Also, I'm already running with a lot of different flavors. I do not want to handle the versionCode in even more flavor variants.

This is not allowed.

```
buildTypes {
    release_beta {
        minifyEnabled false
        testCoverageEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release_beta
        versionCode buildVersionCode()
    }
```

The only options I see left are

1. Can I determine the build type at runtime in my `build.gradle`, and conditionally set the
   versionCode depending on the `buildType`. i.e debug vs release_beta.

Something like...

```
    defaultConfig{
      if(buildTypes.name == "release_beta"){
        versionCode buildVersionCode()
      }else{
       versionCode 99999999999
      }
    }
```

2. Can I have another config besides `defaultConfig`, and only apply it
   to a certain build type, so that I can then set a different
   versionCode for the release_beta buildType.

Something like...

```
    buildTypes {
        release_beta {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled false
            defaultConfig{
              versionCode buildVersionCode()
     }
```

Comment: "Can I determine the build type at runtime in my build.gradle" -- not in the way that you are thinking. The result of running a Gradle build script is not an app, but rather an object model of how to build an app. Only when a particular task from that object model is requested (e.g., `assembleDebug`) do we know the build type, and your `build.gradle` script could well have been last executed several hours ago, when you fired up Android Studio first thing in the morning. "Can I have another config besides defaultConfig" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: Presumably there is a way of accomplishing what you want by iterating over all of the `applicationVariants` after they have been set up, finding all of them associated with your desired build type, and then modifying the version code for each.

Comment: Did you manage to find out more?